# "Знать на зубок": почему "на зубок"?

Tags: фразеология

Знать отлично — знать за зубок. А почему именно "на зубок"? О чем тут изначально шла речь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Знать назубок** - одобр. знать очень твердо, хорошо; выучить наизусть. Выражение связано с пробой колец, золотых монет и т. д. на зуб для проверки их подлинности. На фальшивых или полых изделиях после надкуса оставались вмятины.